# Case insensitive search in man pages

Tags: search, man, less, pager

Is there a way to search man pages case-insensitively?  Using the '/' search feature matches exact case.

Comment: There is no such thing like “search in man page”. Actually it is search in the _pager_ which displays the man page. Depends on the `man` implementation you use and the pager you prefer, but I have `export MANPAGER='less -I'`.

Comment: @manatwork's point is that `-I` means `--IGNORE-CASE, even if the  pattern  contains uppercase letters`, see `man less`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When no other pager is specified, `man` uses `less` to display man pages.

The other answers that involve changing the pager command line are correct, but you can also type `-i` while less is running.  From the less man page:

> <kbd>`-`</kbd> Followed  by one of the command line option letters (see OPTIONS
>     below), this will change the setting of that option and print  a
>     message  describing  the  new  setting.

So typing `-i` while in less changes the setting in the same way that specifying it on the command line would.  I got the hint that this would work from [How do you do a case insensitive search using a pattern modifier using less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828/how-do-you-do-a-case-insensitive-search-using-a-pattern-modifier-using-less), then found the explanation in the man page.

Answer (score 19):

Only if you use caps, not if you just use lower case letters. For example, run `man bash` and try:

- `/invoc`  <== case insensitive
- `/Invoc`  <== case sensitive
- `/INVOC`  <== case sensitive

As @manatwork poited out in the comments, you can also control this behavior by adding `export MANPAGER='less -I'` to your `~/.profile`. The `MANPAGER` variable defines which program is used with the `man` command. The `-I`means (from `man less`):

```
   -I or --IGNORE-CASE
          Like -i, but searches ignore case even if the  pattern  contains
          uppercase letters.
```

Other relevant options are (this one is usually on by default):

```
   -i or --ignore-case
          Causes searches to ignore case; that is, uppercase and lowercase
          are  considered identical.  This option is ignored if any upper‐
          case letters appear in the search pattern; in other words, if  a
          pattern  contains  uppercase  letters, then that search does not
          ignore case.
```

So, if you `export MANPAGER="less -I"; man bash`, you should be able to search for `/iNvOc` in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: +1 Do you happen to know how one can force case sensitivity on an all-lowercase search pattern?

Comment: @JosephR. `man bash | grep -C 5 invoc` but that's cheating.

Comment: Yeah, not exactly the answer I was looking for. This may be worth another question on its own...

Comment: @JosephR. [apparently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=11791328#11791328), you can compile `less` to use PCREs which might do the trick.

Comment: The case-insensitive-for-lower-case only appears to be true if "-i" is specified on the command line.  Without it, all searches are case sensitive.

Comment: @JosephR. It's the same switch – it's a toggle: type `-i` on man page. Feedback toggles between "Case is significant in searches" and "Ignore case in searches".

Answer (score 1):

Since it comes up as the first result on Google, I want to also add that if you start using [Most](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_(Unix)) as your pager, your search will be **case-insensitive by default**. It also adds a few more capabilities like **coloring man pages** and backward search.

To install, use the package manager of your distribution and the package name is "most" everywhere (e.g.: `apt install most`).
Then in the startup file of your shell, e.g., in `~/.bashrc` add the environment variable:

```
export PAGER="most"
```

Don't forget to replace the shell process with a new one so that it can read it (e.g.: `exec bash`).

Also to make it **case-sensitive** (notice: opposite of what the OP has asked for, but the reason I came here :) ) use the `-c` option:

```
export PAGER="most -c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Through the env variable `LESS`:

```
LESS=-I man less
```

You can also include the search string at once:

```
LESS=-I\ +/escape\ key man less
```

Or:

```
LESS='-I +/escape key' man less
```

Even more complex constructions:

```
LESS=+G?[+]cmd man less
```

`+G` - *go to the end of the page*
`?` - *search  backward*
`[+]` - *deprive the special meaning of the character* `+`
That is, we are looking for `'+cmd'` from the end of the man less.

It is very convenient when you need to show a specific place in the manual instead of quoting:

```
LESS=-I\ +8?lesskey man less
```

`+8?` - *Eighth match from the end*

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO. In your shell’s startup config file, do this: export LESS='--IGNORE-CASE'

Or in Fish Shell, run: set -Ux LESS '--IGNORE-CASE'