# How can I search in vim for a pattern that is NOT case sensitive?

Tags: vim, file-search

I occasionally search through files in `vim` or `less` using `/` or `?` but as far as I can tell, the search patterns are case sensitive.

So for example, `/foo` won't find the same things that `/FOO` will.  Is there an way way to make it less strict?  How can I search in `vim` or `less` for a pattern that is NOT case sensitive?

Comment: In `less` searches are case insensitive unless you use a string that contains an upper case letter. So, `foo` will match `Foo` and `FoO` but `Foo` will only match `Foo` and not `foo` etc. Also see here: [less is always case-insensitive](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116395).

Comment: @terdon Interesting! I'm struggling to understand the "why" of having `less` behave that way but I suppose that's a topic for another day.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, for one thing, I find it exceedingly useful when searching through man pages. I'd hate to have it case sensitive. There are quite a few posts about this, also have a look here: [Can I force \`man\` to do lower case sensitive matching?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124282) and here: [Case insensitive search in man pages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101295). In fact, if you don't mind, I'll remove `less` from your question since that is covered quite nicely in the other posts and the answers you've received explain how to do it in vi.

Comment: @terdon Fine by me, although please consider leaving this comment dialogue in as I tend to use both `less` and `vi` and that info is valuable.

Comment: As a point of clarification, I am indeed using `vim` (even though I'm typing `vi`).  Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In `vi` or `vim` you can ignore case by `:set ic`, and all subsequent searches will consider the setting until you reset it by `:set noic`. In `less` there are options `-i` and `-I` to ignore case.

Comment: I would also like to recommend `:set smartcase`, in order to only search case sensitive when at least on uppercase character is used.

Comment: Just for the record, `smartcase` _is_ vim-only. But OP's "vi" is likely vim, so it's worth mentioning/trying.

Comment: @Random832 Yup. Correct.  Updated the original question to mention `vim` instead of `vi`.

Answer (score 33):

Use the `\c` escape sequence:

```
/foo\c
```

See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287440/how-to-do-case-insensitive-search-in-vim

Comment: Note that this can go anywhere in the pattern, so if you decide after starting to type that you want the pattern to be case-insensitive, you can just add `\c` wherever you are—e.g., `/some_very_lo\cng_text`.

Answer (score 3):

In your `.vimrc` file, include

`set ignorecase`

or

`set ic`

To re-enable case sensitivity, use `:set ic!`.

Comment: Hi! This looks OK, but it doesn't add much to the already-accepted answer, now, does it?

Comment: @dhag all of the answers provide a different way of accomplishing the same task. Setting the value in .vimrc allows the setting to persist for other vim sessions.

Comment: @dhag you're right in that this does nothing to solve the OP's issue in less.